# Java interface - Return on method call

Tags: java, interface

I've been struggling a couple of days trying to understand how the code below works.

I simply have: an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Screen {

    protected final Game game;

    public Screen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public abstract void update(float deltaTime);
    public abstract void paint(float deltaTime);
    public abstract void pause();
    public abstract void resume();
    public abstract void dispose();
    public abstract void backButton();

}
```

and an interface:

```
public interface Game {
    public void setScreen(Screen screen);
    public Screen getInitScreen();
}
```

I understood that the interface methods have no body because they say *what* classes can do, not *how*.

Then, when I call the method below from a class that extends the Screen abstract class:

```
game.getInitScreen();
```

What exactly this method will return? A new Screen? But there is nothing on this Screen class...no canvas, no SurfaceView...what's the point of such call?

Comment: It's possible that the game can have multiple screens and `Game` starts with a "initial screen" ... possibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, at run-time, there will be a class that provides a concrete implementation of a `Screen`. Exactly what that `class` is could be determined with something like `game.getInitScreen().getClass().getName()`

Comment: Okay, but `Screen` contains `Game` and `Game` contains `Screen`...seems like a chicken an egg issue to me...

Comment: Pretty normal in Java as parent-child relationship